# get page method java

Tags: java, integer

I am making a project of memory management.

I made a class for pages and now I'm making the RAM class that will handle pages.

I have an alert on this method:

```
public Page<byte[]>[] getPages(Integer[] pageIds){
        Page<byte[]>[] getPages = new Page[pageIds.length];
        for(int i=0; i<pageIds.length ; i++){
            getPages[i] = pages.get(pageIds[i]);
        }
        return getPages;
    }
```

The problem is when I create getPages that should save the pages for all the ids in the array of Integers. How do I fix it?

Comment: i have type safety on "pageIds.length" on second line when i create New Page, becasue the method doesn't know the size of pageIds

Comment: where? this is the constructor:
public RAM(int initialCapacity){
  pages = new HashMap<Integer, Page<byte[]>>(initialCapacity);
 }

Comment: You pass an array to getPages. That array has a length.

Comment: i know! but i get this alert:Type safety: The expression of type Page[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to Page<byte[]>[]

Comment: That's just a warning. You can get over it by adding a cast (see my updated answer), though that would just give you a different warning. Anyway, you don't have to get rid of the warning for the code to work.

Comment: same warning with cast. i will ignore the warning:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the warning you get is `Type safety: The expression of type Page[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to Page<byte[]>[]`.

You can get rid of it by casting :

`Page<byte[]>[] getPages = (Page<byte[]>[])new Page[pageIds.length];`

However, the cast would just give you a different warning :

`Type safety: Unchecked cast from Page[] to Page<byte[]>[]`

Comment: i tried it once, i have a message:
cannot create a generic array of Page<byte[]>

Comment: package memory;

public class Page <T>{


 private int pageId;
 private T content;
 
 public Page(int id, T content){
  this.pageId = id;
  this.content = content;
 }
 
 public int getPageId(){
  return pageId;
 }
 
 public void setPageId(int pageId) {
  this.pageId = pageId;
 }
 
 public T getContent() {
  return content;
 }
 
 public void setContent(T content) {
  this.content = content;
 }
 
 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
  return pageId;
 }